# WordPress admin menu display glitch in Google Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

A recent update to Google Chrome seems to be causing issues with my WordPress admin menus.

[image: Screenshot showing admin menu display glitch]

This is happening on all sites, whether in local development or on the web. The sites are displaying fine on other browsers (Firefox and Safari).

Deactivating all plugins and changing to the default Twentyfifteen theme had no effect on this display glitch.

Is there a known issue with Chrome? Can this be fixed?

Comment: Note that this Chrome bug is still not fixed as of Chrome v45.0.2454.85 m

Comment: You can follow the status of the bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509179


It will probably be resolved in version 46

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This issue has very recently been fixed in Chrome 45.0.2454.93 so there should be no need to use this if you have the latest version of Chrome**

The code below is only left in for reference.

---

You can fix this with CSS:

```
function chromefix_inline_css()
{ 
  wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', '#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }' );
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'chromefix_inline_css');
```

Add that to your theme `functions.php` file and it should fix the problem. There's no check for the Chrome browser specifically, but it appears this fix has no adverse effect on other browsers, so no harm done.

If you just want a plugin to do it: https://github.com/raffjones/chrome-admin-menu-fix

Comment: I can confirm that plugin works as a temporary workaround. Also, there's some suggestion that a future version of Chrome fixes this: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/_T7hln9XMzE/gzaLii9JiiEJ

Comment: Thanks Joe. You are right - looks like Google have sight of the issue now. If it's in the stable public release now a lot more people are going to start making noise about it so I'm hopeful there will be a fix soon.

Comment: Awesome! I was using the js before in my themes, but your new CSS fix is much better. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 11):

**Edit: This issue has now been fixed in all versions of Chrome, on all platforms. Simply update your Chrome to the latest available version for your channel.**

Old answer:

- Go to chrome://flags/#disable-slimming-paint
- Enable the "Disable slimming paint" option.
- Ensure that the "Enable slimming paint" option below it is not turned on.
- Relaunch Chrome.

Fixes it for me. Seems the bug is located in "Slimming Paint", part of the new Blink rendering.

Comment: Yes, worked for me too - this is the best fix as it's not a WordPress problem and should therefore not require a workaround. Nice one!

Comment: Slimming Paint isn't going away though, looks like [it's a permanent change](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/NALTkPHefW0) to Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @zenjiweb. The CSS solution below works fine if there is not going to be a change to Chrome to sort this.

Comment: Slimming Paint isn't going away, but the bug in it will eventually be fixed. For now, leaving it off is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was just pushed to the Stable release of Chrome 45.  I get exactly this messed up display in version 45 of Chrome on both Mac and PC.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps removing Chrome Beta will solve this issue? It did the trick for me :-)

Comment: Yes, this works. I don't ever recall explictly signing up to use Chrome beta, and having to reinstall isn't ideal but it works for me too. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, Michael if I put the workaround in the wrong place!

Comment: This is no longer relevant since at the time this was posted, the Chrome stable version was 44. The beta of that time is now the stable version (45) with the problem still present.

Answer (score 0):

try this for chrome-only

in functions.php:

```
/* fix glitch on chrome for admin menus */
function chromefix_inline_css() { 
    wp_add_inline_style('wp-admin', '@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { #adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); } }');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'chromefix_inline_css');
```

Answer (score -1):

A different variant of raffjones answer. Add this to your theme's functions.php file, and it will patch the issue. I have tested with success in Chrome 45 Mac:

```
// Patch for WP Admin rendering bug in Chrome 45+
function admin_menu_chrome_patch() {
    echo '<style>#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }</style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_menu_chrome_patch');
```

Comment: Interesting that this is a permanent change. Your CSS solution is almost the same as the one I posted earlier, except that for inline styles, it's recommended to attached to the admin_enqueue_scripts hook and use the wp_add_inline_style method - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style. You should also check for Chrome as your fix applies to all browsers.

Comment: @raffjones sorry stripped down my answer a bit. Turns out that while "slimming paint" is permanent, the problem we're seeing is still a Chrome bug. I don't see the need to detect chrome by user agent on the server side though? Expensive server operation to hide CSS that should technically improve browser performance regardless

Comment: I'm hoping someone from Google will weigh in and let us know if there's going to be a fix. I think you're probably right about not bothering with the browser agent check as it's a CSS fix that won't adversly affect other browsers. I still prefer to use the other method of inserting inline CSS via wp_add_inline_style but it's more or less the same thing - just following WordPress best practice.