# Wordpress Dashboard layout broken

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, browser, dashboard

[image]

I have latest v4.3. The same happens in Chrome on my Mac... it happens once I start moving the mouse over links on the left.

I tried with WP 4.1.7 and 4.2.4 and it was the same...

It doesn't seem to happen in Safari, not sure about FF, I think it happened but now it doesn't..

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue (I'm using Opera) and it's damn annoying but I'm not sure it's actually caused by WP itself. I tried in IE 11 (I swear, I don't use it, I opened it just for testing purposes :P ) and issue is not present there.

Comment: Problem is with all browsers. Just refresh it.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944370/wordpress-admin-menu-display-glitch-in-google-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress admin menu display glitch in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944370/wordpress-admin-menu-display-glitch-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 45 has a rendering bug.

If you want to fiddle with internal settings, there is a workaround just posted here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/bug-broken-dashboard-layout

I personally will wait until Chrome 45+ and edit in FF from now on.